# Problem installing Java using Software Center and Terminal

Tags: 12.04, java

I am new at Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I need to install Java 6 or 7. But, when I want to do it using the software center or by terminal it responds me "install failed" and "check your Internet connection". But, I can easily install other software using Software Center and Terminal and there is no problem in my Internet connection.

What should I do now? How can I install Java on Ubuntu?

Comment: do you have any custom sources added for the java packages? PPAs?

Comment: by install from terminal you mean `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install <name of package>` right?

Comment: and have you tried synaptic package manager instead of software center?

Comment: no i haven't use synaptic package manager. I have tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install <name of package>. but still unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more information about installing java here is the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)

I supposed that you mean the Oracle (Sun) Java 6

Do the following if you are planning to install the jre

```
$ wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u34-b04/jre-6u34-linux-i586.bin
 $ chmod u+x jre-6u34-linux-i586.bin
 $ ./jre-6u34-linux-i586.bin
 $ sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
 $ sudo mv jre1.6.0_34 /usr/lib/jvm/
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_34/bin/java" 1
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so" "mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_34/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so" 1
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_34/bin/javaws" 1
```

If you are planning to install the oracle java 6 jdk 32-bit

```
$ wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u34-b04/jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin
 $ chmod u+x jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin
 $ ./jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin
 $ sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
 $ sudo mv jdk1.6.0_34 /usr/lib/jvm/
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_34/bin/java" 1
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_34/bin/javac" 1
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so" "mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_34/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so" 1
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_34/bin/javaws" 1
```

And this important

```
 $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
 $ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
 $ sudo update-alternatives --config mozilla-javaplugin.so
 $ sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

Comment: -------------$ chmod u+x jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin--------- this line is showing no directory error.